# How to selectively suppress code formatting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

I work with large C# files. I use the Edit > Format Document feature of VS2010 (Keyboard shortcut=> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) to format the layout of the code. Sometimes however, I would like to align code in a specific way; for readability.

Question: Is it possible to isolate a section of code which I want the VS formatter to ignore?

Comment: That's not an available option.

Answer (score 0):

How about using

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>

Which is Format Selection

Comment: That would work, until someone else on my team comes along and checks out the file and does a Ctrl+k, Ctrl+d